# datatable pagination Delete row using Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable

I have some issue about the data table pagination. The First Page ajax working but when the second page the ajax is not working :(
This is my sample Code

**This is my data table script**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#my-table2').dataTable({
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "aaSorting": [[ 0, "asc" ]],
         bSort: false,
     }); 
   });
```

**Then the AJAX CODE**

```
      $(document).ready(function() {  

 $(".remove_edot").click(function(){         
     e.preventDefault(); 

     var href = $(this).attr("href");
     var btn = this;     

    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?')) {
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: href,
          dataType: 'json',          
          success: function(response) {
          if (response.status === "success"){           
             $(btn).closest('tr').fadeOut("slow");                           
          }
          else{
            alert("Error");
          }
       }
    });   
    return false;
        }
 });
```

});

please help

Comment: Hey wewe, can you create a jsFiddle to replicate this? Without seeing the wrapping code, we're shooting in the dark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to delegate the event handling to the parent.

```
$('#my-table2').on('click', '.remove_edot', function(e){
  // Your code here
});
```

That's because when datatables creates the second (and subsequent) pages, it removes the table rows from the DOM and adds new ones. Your original code only bound event listeners on any `.remove_edot` elements that were in the DOM when it ran.

`.on()` is only available in jQuery 1.7+, so if you're using a lower version use `.delegate()` - it has the same arguments.